# is there a way to target a specific div using jquery, even though there are more identical divs?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I made an example here http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/108/

When you mouseover `.test` I don't want to affect all, only the closest `.lol` and make it disappear.

I managed to do this using `.next()` but if I have more divs in between test and lol I have to keep adding more `.next()` into the code.

I was wondering if there was a another way of doing this that would be much cleaner?

Comment: If there is a unique parent or the element has some other unique id, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your JsFiddle to work with as many elements you want !
Basically only select the next element with the `.lol` class using jQuery `nextAll()` function, then take the first of the next.

Example :
http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/115/

> $(this).nextAll('.lol:first')

Answer (score 1):

Wrap divs in between hrs and then use $(this).parent().children('div[class="test"] ~ div[class="lol"]')  to select all the .lol divs:

```
<div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="sdf">sdf</div>
    <div class="lol">lol</div> 
</div>
<hr>
<div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="sdf">sdf</div>
    <div class="else">else</div> 
    <div class="lol">lol</div> 
</div> 
<hr>
<div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="sdf">sdf</div>
    <div class="lol">lol</div> 
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $(this).parent().children('div[class="test"] ~ div[class="lol"]').addClass('hide');
        },
        mouseout: function(){
            $(this).parent().children('div[class="test"] ~ div[class="lol"]').removeClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS? It's faster, and less overhead than trying to affect the view using Javascript/jQuery.

```
.test:hover + div + .lol {
    display: none;
}
```

<s>Updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/110/)</s>

Updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/127/)

Comment: css only works when the divs are next to each other. If there is a div in between them it doesn't work.

Comment: There's different selectors for that @NoSssweat. The `+` selector is what you're thinking of. The `~` selector selects all after that selector. So in `E ~ F`, it selects all **F** preceded by **E** as a previous sibling. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Comment: I looked at the updated JSfiddle, but when I hover over the first test, it makes all the other lol's in row 2 & 3 dissapear. I don't want that, I want only the closest one.

Comment: I'd love to know if there is a way to do it with css, if not then I'll go with jquery.

Comment: Oh crap, I interpreted your `<hr>`s as different container divs for some reason. My bad.

Comment: Ok, well then, if your structure is pretty much the same, you can change the selector to `.test:hover + div + .lol` instead. Updated the JSFiddle. You would basically be chaining the divs to link to the next immediate one.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your elements in a container, and then search only the container for an element with the lol class:

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/109/

```
(this).parent().find('.lol').addClass('hide');
```